# Filtering Json into a JSP

Tags: json, jsp, parsing, filtering

Hy!
I need to know how can I filter/parse some json data into a JSP.
It would be in order to create a kind of 'little' API.
I have made one test via PHP, the thing goes like that.
I send a parameter to an URL like this 
records.php?artist='tame impala'

In my php file first I proceed to trim the parameter artist, then I compare to a JSON will all the records and finally I print only the records from 'tame impala'.

Is it possible to do that in a JSP file without any servlet or similar?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: A JSP is a servlet, written using another syntax. But this task should be done by a Java class, like a servlet. A JSP should be used to generate markup. Nothing else. Try something, and come back if you have a problem.

Comment: So is not a good practice to filtering json on a JSP? my problem is that I think I'm gonna have some problems to do a class....have not enough knowledge of Java...

Comment: Then why do you use JSPs in the first place? Learn the Java basics first. Doing that in a JSP would need to embed Java code in the JSP anyway, which is a bad practice, and will make it more difficult than doing it in a regular Java class.

Comment: Dou you think I can find an easy example of that (I mean a class or servlet parsing json)? I know some basics abou Java, but my problem is that I'm using a 'closed' product: [openCms](http://www.opencms.org/en/), I don't know if is simple or not to make a class inside it. Seems that the easey way is by putting the code on the jsp  :(

Comment: There are plenty of free Java JSON parsers out there. Pick one, and read its documentation. Experiment with simple Java code in a class, out of the CMS, then try integrating what you have in the CMS.

Comment: Somebody talk me about Gson ...I do not know if that would help, by the way do you know any one for java dummies?
Thanks again for all!

Comment: Gson is indeed a JSON parser. And it's well documented.

Comment: Do you think that having some methods in a Java Class that filter/parse a JSON by a paramater used pass thru url may be considered a kind of API?